# x-com-declassified and the-bureau

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-synonyms

[x-com-declassified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-declassified) and [the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bureau) should be synonyms for [x-com-the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-the-bureau). Unfortunately the full game title is too long for a tag: [the-bureau-x-com-declassified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bureau-x-com-declassified) but both these tags might be good search terms...

Comment: How about using [tag:xcom-the-bureau] instead?

Comment: @badp That's a lovely answer you left right there in the comments...

Comment: @badp True, that sounds even better. Dammit, why didn't I think of it... Though a synonym from [tag:x-com-declassified] might still make sense for searchability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [xcom-the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-the-bureau) makes enough sense that there is no need to set up synonyms.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't we agree on x-com vs xcom? There's [tag:xcom-enemey-unknown] but [tag:x-com-ufo-defense], [tag:x-com-tftd] and [tag:x-com-series]

Comment: @Zommuter TCO, without dashes

Comment: [TCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_cost_of_ownership)?

Comment: @Zommuter "taken care of"

Comment: close enough m-/ thanks