# Rename [xcom-the-bureau] → [the-bureau-xcom-declassified]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*[The Bureau: XCOM Declassified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bureau:_XCOM_Declassified)* was [previously decided](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7562/47878) to be tagged as [xcom-the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-the-bureau) due to its name being too long for the 25 character limit at the time. Now that we have 35 characters, I'd like to suggest that we rename it, keeping the old one as a synonym.

- [xcom-the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-the-bureau) → [the-bureau-xcom-declassified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bureau-xcom-declassified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done :)

- [xcom-the-bureau](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-the-bureau) → [the-bureau-xcom-declassified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bureau-xcom-declassified)

Comment: I actually fixed it the other day but didn't get a chance to answer the meta.